# Anyone knows what kind of clip mic cover this is?

Tags: microphone, radiomics

I am watching "Hommes à louer " ( http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1589448/ ), a documentary about male prostitution in Canada and it's made me wonder (on the sound/technical side) about this clip microphone.

Since there is a male nipple in the image, just in case, I will not embed the image. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rUHt.jpg

Does anyone know if this is a commercial product from any particular brand? Or maybe it is just some DIY cover for the clip mic? I have tried to google for it a bit but find myself unable to find what this type of covers can be named.

Thank you,
Marcos

edit: forgot to mention they stick it onto the skin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the [Sanken RM-11 rubber mount](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/745486-REG/Sanken_RM11SINGLE_BLACK_Rubber_Microphone_Mount_Black.html). It is not adhesive itself, but we use [topstick](http://www.vapon.com/topstick.htm) to make it adhesive.

You can get them in a few different colors, also there is an RM-11C version that has a built in clip.

I have a bunch of them and love them!

Comment: @Colin Hart - And these are universal for any lav?

Comment: I've used them with lots of different types of lavs - COS-11s (made to go with this accessory), EMWs, B6, E6, Trams, etc... Not sure how it would work with a lav like the Isomax series that has both sides open to the diaphragm. 